# Precise position text rendering in C# using Graphics class

Tags: c#, graphics

I made a program that allows me to make fontmap textures. Most characters on the resulting picture end up correctly, except for some exceptions that bring some problems, as shown in the magnified screenshot below: (Font used is `Arial Narrow` with a `FontStyles.Bold`)

[image: The result]

As you can see, some anti-aliasing pixels have somehow made it into the block for the character "i", and this is not acceptable for the engine I'm working with.

I'm using the following code to render the characters:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
  g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

  Font font = new Font(FontFamily.Families[listFonts.SelectedIndex],
    (float)numSize.Value, checkBold.Checked ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular);

  Size cellSize = GetCellSize(g, textCharSet.Text, font);
  sizeCellSize = cellSize;

  labelCellSize.Text = cellSize.Width + ", " + cellSize.Height;

  int iColumn = 0;
  int iRow = 0;

  string strText = textCharSet.Text;

  for (int i = 0; i < strText.Length; i++) {
    char c = strText[i];

    // ignore carriage returns
    if (c == '\r') {
      continue;
    }

    // handle newline
    if (c == '\n') {
      iColumn = 0;
      iRow++;
      continue;
    }

    // get single character size
    SizeF singleCharSize = g.MeasureString("" + c, font);

    // get shadow values
    int iShadowX = (int)numShadowX.Value;
    int iShadowY = (int)numShadowY.Value;

    // render cell preview
    if (bPreview) {
      g.FillRectangle(i % 2 == 0 ? Brushes.DarkMagenta : Brushes.Fuchsia,
        new Rectangle(iColumn * cellSize.Width, iRow * cellSize.Height, cellSize.Width, cellSize.Height));
    }

    // render shadow of character if needed
    if (checkShadow.Checked && (iShadowX != 0 || iShadowY != 0)) {
      g.DrawString("" + c, font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(
        iColumn * cellSize.Width + Math.Max(0, iShadowX),
        iRow * cellSize.Height + Math.Max(0, iShadowY)), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    }

    // render character
    g.DrawString("" + c, font, Brushes.White, new PointF(
      iColumn * cellSize.Width + -Math.Min(0, iShadowX),
      iRow * cellSize.Height + -Math.Min(0, iShadowY)), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

    iColumn++;
  }
}
```

I have set `TextRenderingHint` before to fix some problems, but it doesn't seem to fix all of them.

Why does the `j` get partially rendered inside of the `i` block, and how can I prevent this from happening while remaining the anti aliasing?

Comment: For this reason I usually render centered within a block (and record the offset for use when using the texture)

Comment: It's most probably that the GridFit rendering hint only fits the original glyph into the grid, it doesn't take into account the aliased pixels. You could try rendering each glyph to a render target/surface and then render this to your checked background instead of rendering directly to the graphics object. You might need to make a larger target area than is necessary and render to the centre of it

Comment: @Charleh That's actually a very good idea. If you post that as answer I will mark it as the accepted answer if there's no other appropriate answers.

Comment: This is normal, the point of anti-aliasing is to create the illusion of smaller pixels.  Can't do that without coloring outside the lines.  The only way to avoid it without drastic perf consequences is to use TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to create an area larger than you need for each glyph as a separate graphics object, then render the glyph to the centre of the target graphics object. You could use `MeasureString` and then add a buffer value of a few pixels around the object.

Once you've done this, you will need to find the extents of the rendered glyphs anti-aliased pixels, so I assume that will be all pixels that don't have a zero alpha value. Once you've found this you can calculate the "used" area in your target and render it onto the main graphics object in the required location.

I can't give you code though as I don't have much experience with the `Graphics` object in .NET

Answer (score 2):

Try using GetCharABCWidths which will give you the dimensions you need.  Look at the B spacing which gives the width of the black part of the glyph.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144857(v=vs.85).aspx

You might also try using GetGlyphOutline and the GlyphMetrics structure to get the black box area of the glyph.

Yes the anti-aliasing will be accounted for especially in the GetGlyphOutline/GlyphMetrics option, and IIRC GetCharABCWidths does also account for this.

(Apologies, I upgraded to IE 11 and can't use JavaScript on this site for some reason...)

Comment: Will this count the anti aliased pixels as well? I believe `GetCharABCWidths` is used in `Graphics.MeasureString`, is it not?